# python fabric output hangs

Tags: python, fabric

I am trying a very basic fabric code like this:

```
from fabric.api import run, task

@task
def test():
    run("find /tmp -type f")
```

The output however gets stuck like this forever:

```
[root@e059fb ]# fab test -i tej.pem -H tej@10.90.242.76
[tej@10.90.242.76] Executing task 'test'
[tej@10.90.242.76] run: find /tmp -type f
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/qwer.pid
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/install.pid
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/xxxx
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/pki_data1381109216648547511.tmp
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/component_event.xlf5716431074152235003.jar
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/MIME3880781677960930334.tmp
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/component_event.xlf2448949157221874062.jar
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/pki_data4307187884067858048.tmp
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/MIME492598143052197490.tmp
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/component_event.xlf6922738826235471484.jar
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/xxxxx
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/component_event.xlf5514972543465832532.jar
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/MIME7456325891227527672.tmp
[tej@10.90.242.76] out: /tmp/component_event.xlf7878309880872461565.jar
[tej@10.90.242.76] out:
```

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks there is some pty related configuration wrong for this user and VM.
Even I was not able to run the command from SSH -t and -T. Both of them hung up.

```
ssh -t -i tej.pem tej@10.90.242.76 "ls -ltr /tmp"
```

On a different machine I was able to pass through and is working fine.